# Django: How to ignore parts of code in a function when testing

Tags: django, unit-testing

I don't care what `some_other_functipn_2` and `some_other_function` does. I just need to assert that `test_target` is called. This is a simplified version of my code. I know this can be done by patching but my code just has too many parts to patch. Is there anyway to ignore everything else except the target?

```
def abc():
 a = some_other_function()
 b = some_other_functipn_2(a)
 test_target(b)
```

Comment: you test_targer require return from b which also require return of a functions, don't think you can run test_target() unless you can set b value yourself or mock it

Comment: Any reason not to have a  variable MY_UNLIKELY_NAME_TESTING? (in settings or app config) which, if set and containing a particular value, ignores the return value (or whatever).  Your tests are the only thing that ever sets it. I can understand people using compiled languages disliking this being in production code (because Heisenbugs). But with Python, if a variable gets corrupted, something is globally, BADLY wrong  and everything is about to go very pear-shaped anyway.